# Centre a Navigation Bar with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have no formal training in HTML and CSS, but web development is a hobby of mine, and I have a problem that I am really struggling to get for my personal website.  Here: [image: image attached,]

You can see that the elements of my unordered list are not centred on the black unordered list background; in the `body` tag:

```
        <ul>
            <li><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="resume.html">Bio</a></li>
            <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="store.html">Store</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Previously, in the `head` tag, I declare the style for each of these elements in the document, and what to do if the cursor hovers over it:

```
    <style>
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            background-color: black;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        li {
            float: left;
        }
        li a {
            display: block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            border-width: thick;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        li a:hover {
            background-color: darkgray;
        }
    </style>
```

The concept I've tried more times than not is if you have a `div` tag around `li` and you centre that.  But, I am going in circles.  So how do you centre the white lettering while keeping an equal amount of black space on either side?  Thank you very much!

For reference, I have branched out from [this tutorial.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions#How_the_Web_works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a div wrapper to ul element:

```
<div class="ul-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="resume.html">Bio</a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="store.html">Store</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

And then set styles for div like this:

```
.ul-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
}
```

And add display: inline-block; to ul styles.

```
ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: inline-block;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you!  That works!  Just a quick question for my programming knowledge: when you have `.ul-wrapper` what does the dot do?

Comment: Dot is a class selector, that means you are selecting all elements with that class. You can find more about selectors here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox with `justify-content: center;`

For example

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, `ul` and `li` are `display: block;`. In order to achieve your result you need to wrap your list in a centered div and set the background color on the div.

Add a wrapper to your HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="resume.html">Bio</a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="store.html">Store</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then, in your CSS

```
.wrapper {
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
```